# SQL Server 2005 xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

The following code works fine when executed directly in Sql server:

```
DECLARE @cmd sysname
set @cmd = 'dir "C:\A_Projects"'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

but when I try to create a stored procedure as follows:

```
create procedure zz
 (@cmdin varchar(255))
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdin
```

I get a message

> 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create procedure zz (@cmdin varchar(255))
AS --missed this
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdin
```